How does an Authentication Provider match a user or determine which method to execute?
I'm implementing SSO for an Experience Cloud site where the identity provider is AWS Cognito.
It seems the other party that manages the Cognito side has customised the settings such that authentication fails when using the default auth handler or no handler even though the users are created on both sides.
I would like to understand how the handler determines whether to execute the createUser method or the updateUser method. Furthermore, I'd like to understand how the handler determines what the value for the input parameter "userId" should be.
After adding some logging I've noticed that Auth.UseData is populated with some data, but the username field is blank.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.
